# How to add more than 2 views to a view stack?

Tags: javascript, iphone, list, dashcode

I have been having problems simply adding more than 2 views to the stack through the Dashcode GUI interface. I have seen how to do that programmatically, but is there a way to statically keep extra views within the stack?

I am actually okay with using a different stack, but the problem there is that I have to add another browser area and it get's very ugly and messy in the editor.

Thanks for the help,

Connor

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured it out by now, but there is a Subviews section of the StackLayout's inspector. Just click on the + button to add a view. (Or click on the - button to remove a view.)  You can move the view order up and down in order by dragging and dropping them in this inspector panel.

Hope this helps!